# How to connect audio to MediaStream from Three.JS AudioContext

Tags: javascript, three.js, web-audio-api

I am instanting a MediaStream from a canvas. I need to connect audio to this stream from the audio streaming from Three.js.

I have tried many things, but the most succinct is in the code provided. Is the stream added but the audio just not audible?

```js
const context: AudioContext = ThreeAudioContext.getContext();
const destination = context.createMediaStreamDestination();
const source = context.createMediaStreamSource(destination.stream);
source.connect(destination);
stream.addTrack(destination.stream.getAudioTracks()[0]);
```

I have also tried this to see if the audio is connected, but I still can't hear anything.

```js
const context: AudioContext = ThreeAudioContext.getContext();
const destination = context.createMediaStreamDestination();
const source = context.createMediaStreamSource(destination.stream);

const gainNode = context.createGain();
gainNode.gain.value = 1;

source.connect(gainNode);
gainNode.connect(destination);
stream.addTrack(destination.stream.getAudioTracks()[0]);
```

I want to hear audio from Three.JS, but I am not hearing anything. I have volume adjustable in the game itself. Could that be affecting things? I should note that I am calling canvas.captureStream() first, then performing this "track addition" then instantiating a recorder.

Comment: A runnable snippet would be very helpful.  Can you provide one?

Comment: @RaymondToy Thanks for replying! I was able to solve it and provided a solution that should help people in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For developers in the FuTuRe:

```
const context: AudioContext = ThreeAudioContext.getContext();
const destination = context.createMediaStreamDestination();
this.audioListener.getInput().connect(destination);
this.backgroundGainNode.connect(destination);
stream.addTrack(destination.stream.getAudioTracks()[0]);
```

In short, to connect audio to the MediaRecorder, call createMediaStreamDestination and connect the gainNode (volume node) to the newly created destination. Then, add the track to the stream.

Couple of hiccups I had:
- All gain nodes you connect need to be under the same audio context.
- If you want to connect audio to the stream, even though it may not be audible, you need to create an independent GainNode.

Of course, I say GainNode with the understanding you might be using a different type of AudioNode, but I assume 95% of people just want audio to play without any alteration besides volume.